# ASP.NET Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webforms

We have a ASP.NET MVC site with some legacy webforms pages. Recently some hits on these pages ends with the following error in log:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent.
at System.Web.HttpCookieCollection.Add(HttpCookie cookie)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Apparently the stack trace does not contain any user code.

We have failed to reproduce the error. The error happens on GETs and POSTs and different user agents.

`Response.Buffer` and `Response.BufferOutput` is set to `true`.

Comment: On which pages does this happen? Randomly on all or just on a certain page?

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu On the several remaining webforms-pages.

Comment: The error is quite self explanatory. The webforms pages you have must be writing cookies in a form not agreed by the MVC pipeline. Unless you show us more code there's no way we can help.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu I'm confused that the stack doesn't contain any user code, so I can't imagine which code leads to the error.

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard to have a look at the code and see where cookies are set.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu We have several places in code where cookies are set and none of them are in the stack. Under which circumstances user code can lead to errors with such a stack?

Comment: That's stated in the error message: "Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent". So basically are you start sending content to the browser you cannot add/modify cookies.

Comment: do you get solution ? source code controller ?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is quite self explanatory. Your code tries to add/modify cookies after the response is set.

You need to walk-through your code and checkthe sections that write cookies.

Even if your code looks ok at the first glance, make sure that you don't have `async` content loading up before your cookies are written.

Your post suggest that this errors occur randomly so most likely it's a issue related to `async`. It's a race situation: sometimes the `async` completes before cookie creation but other times it doesn't, hence the random error.

Comment: The site is running on .NET 4 and ASP.NET MVC 3, so there is no async code.

Comment: This simplifies your problem greatly. You only have to verify that your code does not write cookies after the response is sent.